# Python - 'ascii' codec can't decode byte \xbd in position

Tags: python, unicode, web-scraping, lxml

I'm using LXML to scrape some text from webpages.  Some of the text includes fractions.

```
5½
```

I need to get this into a float format.  These fail:

```
ugly_fraction.encode('utf-8')  #doesn't change to usable format
ugly_fraction.replace('\xbd', '')  #throws error
ugly_freaction.encode('utf-8').replace('\xbd', '')  #throws error
```

Comment: There is no native functionality to turn a fraction character into a float. All your encoding/decoding will ever acheive is to convert one character to another. You need a much more comprehensive function to recognise each fraction and convert it to a numeric value. Some kind of dictionary lookup with unicode keys mapped to equivalent float value.

Comment: that is what i am trying to do with the replace() function but i can't get it to work either.  how can i do it?

Comment: @SpliFF: Yes there is native functionality to do that.

Comment: are you looking to extract the actual float value(s) or do you just intend to convert all fraction representations to decimal ones in a string?

Comment: @abarnert: Care to elaborate on that?

Comment: @SpliFF: I'm writing an answer to do that, because it would be silly to cram into a comment.

Comment: As a side note, I think you might be happier with a `decimal.Decimal` or `fraction.Fraction` here than a `float`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`unicodedata.numeric`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.numeric):

> Returns the numeric value assigned to the Unicode character unichr as float. If no such value is defined, default is returned, or, if not given, ValueError is raised.

Note that it only handles a single character, not a string. So, you still need to write the code that turns a "mixed fraction" made up of an integer and a fraction character into a float. But that's easy. For example. You just need to come up with the rule for how mixed fractions are represented in your data. For example, if pure ints, pure fractions, and ints followed by a fraction with no space in between them are the only possibilities, this works (including raising some kind of reasonable exception for all invalid cases):

```
def parse_mixed_fraction(s):
    if s.isdigit():
        return float(s)
    elif len(s) == 1:
        return unicodedata.numeric(s[-1])
    else:
        return float(s[:-1]) + unicodedata.numeric(s[-1])
```

Comment: +1 for teaching me about a previously unknown library! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks SO MUCH. Very helpful answer for a really, really annoying problem. Up-voted